# How can you determine how fast (m/s) heat will travel through a material being heated on one end?

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I was wondering how fast heat will travel through rectangular glass bottle, heated on a tray under vacuum.

I work in a lab where an inert atmosphere glovebox is used, and when moving glass bottles into the box, they must sit under a low to medium vacuum on a heated tray at 120C, overnight, to remove any moisture. One the members in my lab emphasized that it is important that the glass bottles sit on their long side while drying (to maximize surface area contact with the heated tray).

To me this seemed unimportant because since its under vacuum, the only significant mode of heat transfer, is conduction. So if the bottle is not losing any heat to its surroundings,  the entire bottle would reach 120C slower than if it were laying on its side, but considering it will be in there for 12+ hours, I'd think its insignificant whether to maximize the surface area (the greater surface area orientation is probably 3 times greater).

I wanted to understand how fast the heat would travel through the bottle to determine if it would make a significant difference, but I really dont think it would... Any input?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the solution for 1D transient heat conduction through a slab and plug in your bottles material properties to get a quantitative estimate.  Or better yet do an experiment yourself since you have a perfectly equipped lab to test the two orientations.  But glass is a very poor conductor, so don't be surprised if it takes quite a long time. Also, not only surface area is less in the upright case, but the distance the heat has to travel would then be longer to heat the whole bottle.